# When to use absolute pressure or gauge pressure in fluid mechanics problems

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

[image: Question]

So I was doing this practice problem and for the result that I obtained I used absolute pressure but in the solutions it uses the gauge pressure. Just unsure why gauge pressure over absolute pressure is used?

Comment: Show your calculations

Comment: For an incompressible fluid, you can use either pressure, but for a compressible fluid, you need to use absolute pressure.  In your calculation using absolute pressure, did you include the pressure force acting on the outside of the pipe bend?